# Laravel session not being forgot before redirect

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to forget some session key's and then redirect the user (`redirect()` doesn't work so I use `header()`) to an external website.

I have noticed however that these session keys are persisting.

```php
class CognitoUserProvider
{    
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendToLoginPage(): void
    {
        request()->session()->forget([ 'access_token', 'id_token', 'refresh_token' ]);
        
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost/'
        ]);
        
        session([ 'redirect_url' => URL::current() ]);
        header("Location: https://{$this->domain}/login?$query&scope=email+openid");
        exit;
    }
```

```php
// AuthServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    
    Auth::extend('cognito', static function () {
        return new CognitoUserProvider();
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is inside a controller ?

Comment: @ml59 updated post to show how the code is called better

Comment: this is weird, but I faced it before and sloved it by `session()->save();` use it before update or delete a session

Comment: do not send headers yourself just **return** a redirect response ... you are also calling `exit` which is killing the current script/request before the framework can actually do clean up ... like saving the session ... you are not letting the response go through the middleware stack or kernel at this point, so there are tons of things not happening ... don't do it this way, **return** a redirect response and let the framework handle it

Comment: there is also the `away` method of the redirector for external redirects

Comment: @lagbox I will try this again, couldn't get it to work before for some reason

Comment: @lagbox think the issue is i'm just providing an instant of my `CognitoUserProvider` class to `Auth::extend`, so guessing this is calling my `authenticate` method in a way that doesn't allow for `redirect()` to be used?

Comment: looks like you made a guard i suppose but not sure what would actually be calling that method ... most likely up the line you need to be returning a response not there as nothing is doing anything with the return value most likely